# Risks of Using System.Threading.Timer in an ASP.Net/SignalR Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, signalr

We're running SignalR in a stand-alone ASP.Net app running in a virtual directory off our main ASP.Net website.

In our SignalR hub implementation, we have a static `ConcurrentDictionary<int, UserState>` variable maintaining some light-weight user state across individual connections. Over time that variable will be added to based upon client-side actions (i.e. as new users start interacting with our website). This variable is essentially providing some simple state tracking across connections.

We don't particularly want to add a special SignalR backplane which would require additional infrastructure dependencies as our data load is likely to be relatively lightweight and tracking this in-memory should be sufficient.

When a user has been inactive for a long-enough period of time (let's say 1 hour) we want to remove them from the dictionary variable. Whatever process does this should be *guaranteed* to run on a consistent basis - so, not dependent upon user behaviour, but instead upon a timed duration.

I have what I believe to be a good solution for doing this:

```
public class UserStateService : IUserStateService
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, UserState> recentUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, UserState>();
    private static Timer timer;

    public static void StartCleanup()
    {
        timer = new Timer( CleanupRecentUsers, null, 0, 60000 );
    }

    public static void StopCleanup()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
    }

    private static void CleanupRecentUsers( object state )
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var oldUsers = recentUsers.Select( p => p.Value ).Where( u => u.LastActionTime.AddHours( 1 ) > now );

        foreach ( var user in oldUsers )
        {
            UserState removedUser;
            recentUsers.TryRemove( user.UserId, out removedUser );
        }
    }

    // other code for adding/updating user state.
}
```

As mentioned, *I think* this is a good solution. However, I'm not very conversant in thread management (though I'm aware that dealing with static objects in ASP.Net is dangerous).

`StartCleanup()` and `StopCleanup()` are called once each at the start and end of the application lifecycle, respectively. The `UserStateService` is supplied to our `Hub` classes via our IoC container (Structure Map) and is currently not scoped with any special lifecycle handling (i.e. it's not `Singleton` or thread-scoped, simply per-instance request).

We're already using static concurrent dictionaries in our production app and they're working fine without any known instances of performance issues. What I'm not sure about is running a `Timer` loop here.

So, my question is, are there any obvious risks here relating to threads being blocked/locked (or CPU use generally going out of control for any reason) that I need to mitigate or which could make this approach unworkable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no particular problem with using a `Timer` in the way that you suggest.

However, there are a couple of problems with your code.

First, you have:

```
var oldUsers = recentUsers
               .Select( p => p.Value )
               .Where( u => u.LastActionTime.AddHours( 1 ) > now );
```

That will delete any user whose last activity was within the last hour. So anybody you saw a minute ago will be removed. The result is that your `recentUsers` list will probably be empty most of the time. At best, it will contain users who were last seen at least an hour ago.

I think you want to change that to `<`. Or, to think about it another way:

```
.Where((now - u.LastActionTime) > TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

There might also be a race condition in that a user selected for removal might make a request before the removal actually occurs, so you end up removing a user that just made a request. The time window for that race condition is pretty narrow, though, and probably isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, you're correct there Jim. I always get temporal calculations wrong like that! :D I like the approach you suggest, it seems to be much more understandable than the one I used initially. As for the race condition, it's possible but I'm not overly concerned - it won't happen often, nor will it have a major impact when it does happen. Thanks for pointing it out though. Cheers,